# how to call controller method from lightning action

Tags: javascript, lightning, custom-button

Normally in classic ,we can call controller from javascipt button .
how we can achieve this in lightning.

Comment: This is very well documented and there is a great tutorial on  [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules),  additionally, there are plenty of examples on this forum on how to achieve this. Please put some effort into researching prior to posting here. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP clearly did not put any research effort prior to posting.

Answer (score 2):

See [Calling a Server-Side Method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm). Specifically, you first get an Action, set any Parameters, provide a Callback, then Enqueue the Action. Eventually, the framework calls the server's method, and returns the result to your callback.

```
clientSideMethod: function(component, event, helper) {
  var action = component.get("c.serverSideMethod");
  action.setParams({ name1: value1, name2: value2 });
  action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
    // Process result here
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Instead of a JavaScript button, you typically create a Component using code similar to above, then create a Quick Action for the Component, and finally add the Quick Action to the Page Layout for the object.